# Block comments after the closing date (democracyos)

Tags: node.js

I installed democracyos in form docker.
I would like users not to be able to comment after the closing date of voting or poll.

what to do?

Comment: Is this a question about programming? If it is about configuring a tool it might belong to a different site of the StackExchange network.

Comment: Yes, this question refers to the programming of the tool democracyos, because this change can only be done in the back office.

Comment: As nobody was able to answer this might mean that your question doesn't provide enough information. You should [edit] your question to add more information instead of writing answers in comments. I'm still not sure if you have to modify the code of "democracyos" (Would be related to programming and on-topic here.) or if this is possible by modifying its configuration. (Would belong to a different site.)

Comment: Can you help me direct my request to the right group because I am new to the forum.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what is the right place to ask. If there is a community for "democracyos" you should try there first. Otherwise see what you find on https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology Maybe the "Web Applications" site https://webapps.stackexchange.com/